# AWS light sail node server

Tags: node.js

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8701
Error: pm failed, exit with status  1
```

why i'm getting this error while running slc start on AWS light sail node server ?I can't find more documentation on this topic so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check have you changed to Production mode and you are getting PORT and IPAddress from process.env